# Private IP for Azure VM and DNS name

Tags: azure, dns, virtual-machine

Is it possible to assign a private IP to a VM nic which can then be referred to internally as myname.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com (for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would be possible with private dns, you can either create and manage your own dns server inside the vnet and point vms to that, or create a private dns zone in azure and link that to a vnet (although, I'm not sure dns zones for `azure.com` are supported, even private ones).